# Playing uploaded video with Django

Tags: python, django

I am not able to play video on my Django website. I think something is wrong in my views.py render function

videoplay.html:

```
{% block contents %}
  <video name='demo' controls autoplay width='50%' height='40%'>
    <source src="{{STATIC_URL}}sample1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  </video>
{% endblock %}
```

Included this in  settings.py:

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`
```

Views.py is:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 from django.conf import settings
 from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
 from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
 from uploads.core.models import Document
 from uploads.core.forms import DocumentForm
  def index(request):
     return render(request, "core/videoplay.html")`
```

[I am getting a play button and streaming line on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUY0r.png)

Comment: What does the dev console look like.  I am guessing it will be that the video source is not loading because I'm not sure that you are loading the static file correctly.  I'd probably do {% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: Actually I am handling video file and not image file that's why it won't work.I have already tried this .I am sure  something needs to be added in my render request.

Comment: Check the rendered HTML to see if the src contains correct URL. I too would guess there's something wrong with your STATIC tag and directory setup.

Comment: I just replaced my source tag with this <source src="{{MEDIA_URL}}sample1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source> and it is working now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `STATIC_URL` is where your static files are located such as CSS, Template Images, Javascript etc. There is a special [Template Tag for Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) in Django called `{% static %}`.

To generate the full url to where the static files are located, you use the template tag like this:

```
{% load static %}
<video src="{% static "/videos/demo.mp4" %}">
```

The `MEDIA_URL` is where your media files are located. Media files are uploaded files that change during the applications lifetime. They are not necessarily there at deployment but can be uploaded at any time by users or admins on the website.

Media files are set as fields on the model like this:

```
class DemoVideo(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="videos")
```

They are accessed like this `demovideo.video.url` so in your template it would be `src="{{demovideo.video.url}}`.

Check if your file is a media or static file, and access it in the template in the correct way described above.